# CloudWatch InSights: how to extract/query json object array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We have logs published to CloudWatch like this(flattened JSON data using `json.dumps()`):

```
[
  {"Value": 9, "id": "ia-122"}, 
  {"Value": 13, "id": "ia-123"}, 
  {"Value": 14, "id": "ia-100"}
]
```

In the above logs, there're 3 objects in an array.
When I query from CloudWatch Insight with query expression like this:

```
field @message
| parse '"Value": *,' as value
| filter value > 12
```

The log provided above won't be returned since the first value is 9 (not bigger than 12).

How can I query to get the correct result?
[Note: the number of objects in a single log is not always 3]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is tricky to do so. Modified my logs into this:

```
{"Value": 9, "id": "ia-122"}

{"Value": 13, "id": "ia-123"}

{"Value": 14, "id": "ia-100"}
```

as 3 separate records.